# My react app does not fetch the data from firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have a firebase real time database, my react app does not fetch the data.

I followed the instructions. Tried many different ways, none work. All the data below is right in my app, i just replaced it with xxx here in thread

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "xxxxx",
authDomain: "xxxx",
databaseURL: "xxxx",
projectId: "xxxx",
storageBucket: "xxxx",
messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
appId: "xxxx"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default firebase;

export default class OpportunitiesPage extends Component {
state = {
    cards: []
}
componentDidMount() {
    const events = firebase.database().ref("cards");
    events.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        this.setState({cards: snapshot.val()});
    })


}
```

Comment: Are you using firestore or realtime database?

Comment: firebase - realtime database

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed it. I did not include in the rules:
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }